# pyodbc parameterized insert for Impala ODBC Driver

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, impala

I am attempting to do parameterized insert query using pyodbc and Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala but it is not working.
I am trying to execute the following query.

```
   import pyodbc
   insert_query = "insert into table_name(id,name,price) values(?,?,?)"
   cursor.execute(insert_query,1,"Apples","20 dollars")
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
The SQL contains 0 parameter markers but 3 parameters were supplied, 'HY000'
```

If I execute the query using Python formatting like this it WORKS:

```
query_format = "insert into table_name(id,name,price) values({},\"{}\",\"{}\")".format(1,"Apples","20 dollars")
cursor.execute(query_format)
```

But I really want to specify parameters separately because I would want to do ***cursor.executemany()*** to do batch inserts later on and using the formatting approach forces me to use for loop.

Instead of sending values separately , I used tuple too , a list too. Nothing works. Why is it not recognizing "?" as a parameter marker?

Python - 3.7.4,
Pyodbc - 4.0.27,
Anaconda - 1.7.2,
OS - Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As resolved on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/874), this is an issue with the ODBC driver in question, not a problem with pyodbc.

Comment: Yes. Thank you :)